# On entire functions with prescribed zeros

Tags: complex-analysis, analysis

I want to find an entire function with zeros at m+in where m and n are integers. I get a difficulty in making the index natural number for both m and n to write the infinite product. Please help me.

Comment: What do you mean? Are you after an entire function $f$ such that *all* numbers $m+ni$ (with $m,n\in\mathbb Z$) are zeros of $f$?

Comment: The aim is to find an entire function with this zeros using weirstraus factorization method.